# Trouble in getting rid of spaces in MySql

Tags: mysql, string, ascii, space, spaces

I have a column in MySql that contains a description of a products. Sometimes the description contain more the one space between words and I would like to turn it into one space so I've found it with this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM `database`.`PRODUCTS` 
 WHERE `PRODUCTS`.`description` LIKE '%  %'
```

and then repaired it by:

```
 UPDATE `database`.`PRODUCTS` 
 SET `PRODUCTS`.`description` = REPLACE(`PRODUCTS`.`description`,'  ',' ')
```

But it doesn't remove all the double spaces! There are some kind of "special" spaces with (I suspect) different ascii code - `0xA0,0xC2`

How can I `SELECT` it and remove it?

Thanks

Comment: What about running your query Twice?!

Comment: I run it in recursive script in PHP.. it get stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not 'special' spaces - they are not ascii codes - if they are in your database then you've got bugs in the code which put them there.

Why not just replace them?

```
....
SET PRODUCTS.description = REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
       REPLACE(PRODUCTS.description
             ,CHAR(160),' ')
           , CHAR(194), ' ')
       , '  ', ' ');
```