# Replacing ascii code with spaces using mysql

Tags: mysql

I tumbled across this post [Trouble in getting rid of spaces in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115485/trouble-in-getting-rid-of-spaces-in-mysql) . I have a similar problem with regards to ascii codes. Ascii codes such as DLE, CAN, FS, GS but to cut it short it range from Dec 16 to Dec 31(OCT 020 to OCT 037).

The code in the post is like this

```
UPDATE ANIMALS
SET PRODUCTS.description = REPLACE(
REPLACE(
   REPLACE(PRODUCTS.description
         ,CHAR(160),' ')
       , CHAR(194), ' ')
   , '  ', ' ');'
```

My question is what will I change if my table name is `ANIMALS` and the column name is `description` and I want to delete ascii codes such as the ones I stated before the code.

Sorry for asking an easy question but I'm just new in mysql. Pplease help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well... this is as far as I know still not a thing MySQL does in a concise way but only by replacing character by character.

Following your pattern and laying it out in a semi readable manner it gets almost ridiculous, but should work for a one time update of the table;

```
UPDATE ANIMALS
SET description = 
REPLACE(
 REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
     REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
        REPLACE( 
         REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
              REPLACE(
               REPLACE(description,
               CHAR(16),''),
              CHAR(17),''),
             CHAR(18),''),
            CHAR(19),''),
           CHAR(20),''),
          CHAR(21),''),
         CHAR(22),''),
        CHAR(23),''),
       CHAR(24),''),
      CHAR(25),''),
     CHAR(26),''),
    CHAR(27),''),
   CHAR(28),''),
  CHAR(29),''),
 CHAR(30),''),
CHAR(31),'');
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e9fc/1).

If you need to do it more regularly, you're probably better off creating a function that does it for you;

```
CREATE FUNCTION STRIP(input VARCHAR(21844)) RETURNS VARCHAR(21844)
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 16;
  LOOP
   SET input = REPLACE(input, CHAR(i), '');
   IF i = 31 THEN
    RETURN input;
   END IF;
   SET i = i + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
//
```

...and then just use it for the update;

```
UPDATE animals SET description=STRIP(description)
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41745/1).

...and always remember to back up your database before running potentially destructive SQL from random people on the Internet.